# How to retrieve the id of the most recent insert - VisualFoxPro9

Tags: sql, swagger, visual-foxpro

After inserting a record into VisualFoxPro9, I would like to include the ID in the swagger response.

The ID is generated with the default value: `newId("database name")`.

I have tried using `LASTVAL()`, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, and `IDENT_CURRENT()`, none of which seemed to retrieve the last inserted ID.

To Summarize,
How can I return the ID generated by "newId()" after inserting a new data entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newid("database name") is a custom function that you know of.
There are at least 2 ways to get that value:

After an insert, your record pointer is on that record, you could simply check the value of id. ie:

```
insert into yourTable (someColumn) values ('someValue')
newId = yourTable.Id
```

Since that newid("database name") is a custom function of yours, it doesn't need to be inserted via default. You could explicitly get its value and insert. ie:

```
newId = newId("database name")
insert into yourtable ;
(id, somecolumn) values ;
(m.newId, 'someValue')
```

Note: I would suggest using a backend database like postgreSQL, MS SQL server ... instead of VFP's own tables.